# Without using local variables, how could I loop through a c string stored in a character array so that I can check to see if a character is within it?

Tags: c++, while-loop, boolean-logic

I'm trying to implement a bool function that returns true if a character c is within char array charset. However the given instructions specify that I am not to use local variables. I'm assuming local variables include those within for loops such as int i. Below is my current code using a for loop. If I'm not to use local variables, I know it would require a while loop, but my question then is what would be the condition of the while loop?

```
bool isInSet(char c, const char charset[]){
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
    {
        if(c == charset[i])
            return true;
        
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `bool isInSet(char c, const char charset[]) { return strchr(charset, c)?true:false; }`.  See [strchr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strchr).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Shouldn't it just be `return strchr(charset, c);`? The ternary is unnecessary.

Comment: @sweenish Yeah, just return `strchr(charset, c)`.  Now waiting for "we haven't learned that yet...", otherwise, I will post this as an answer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  You would be correct, we have not learned that yet..., but the instructions also say no function calls. I don't know if this counts.

Comment: @ajcheng12 What else do those instructions say, so that we know exactly what can and cannot be used?  The original post doesn't mention anything about no functions being used.  This is why questions that have all these restrictions requires *all* of those restrictions posted up-front.  If you are not sure, go back to your teacher and ask for clarification.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The only rules for this problem is no function calls or local variables are allowed.

Comment: @ajcheng12, *technically*, `c` and `charset` are themselves local variables of `isInSet()`. So, the rules are more like that you are not allowed to introduce *additional* local variables.

Answer (score 1):

> what would be the condition of the while loop?

The `while` loop could use the passed-in pointer as the loop condition.

```
bool isInSet(char c, const char charset[])
{
    while (*charset)  // loop until we find the terminating null character
    {
        if (*charset == c)
            return true;
        ++charset;  // go to next position
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. This worked and I now understand that I can reverse the logic in a while loop so no variable needs to be initialized for its condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your char array is const, however if you can remove that const, you can use something like this:

```
while(*(charset) != '\0'){
    //your logic;
    charset++;
}
```

Comment: Figured it out but I will keep this in mind when removing a constant. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to remove the const at all in order to use such a loop. The const in question is attached to what is being pointed at, not the pointer itself.